# VC++ structure compare between dll and application

Tags: visual-c++, dll, structure

My application calls a dll and updates an application structure with a dll structure.
But there is a extra field in the application structure (bool enable).

When i try to assign my application struture.enable, i am getting the same updated with a junk value.

How can i check if the sizes of the structure defined in dll and the structure defined in application have the same syntax.

I cannot change anything in the dll.

i want the application structure to be initialized with zero allways if that field is not present in the dll structure.

I am providing the code below,

```
///// ** structure definition in the dll called application ** //////
typedef struct
{
    DWORD   Size;   
    bool    mode;   
    BYTE    check;  
    DWORD   time_1; 
    DWORD   time_2; 



} STR_INTERFACE;

///// ** structure definition in the application ** //////


typedef struct
{
    DWORD   Size;  
    bool    mode;  
    BYTE    check; 
    DWORD   time_1;
    DWORD   time_2;

    bool enable; 


} STR_INTERFACE;


///
///mypassedstr will conatin the updated structure pointer with the 
///structure members updated by the dll

int MY_Appli_function::Interface_1_func ( LPCTSTR name_1,  LPVOID mypassedstr )
{


    STR_INTERFACE mycodestr;
        STR_INTERFACE* mynewstr = (STR_INTERFACE*)mypassedstr;

        mycodestr.Size    = mynewstr->.Size   ;
        mycodestr.mode    = mynewstr->.mode   ;
        mycodestr.check   = mynewstr->.check  ;
        mycodestr.time_1  = mynewstr->.time_1 ;
        mycodestr.time_2  = mynewstr->.time_2 ;
        mycodestr.enable  = mynewstr->.enable ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

pack your struct with #pragma pack(1)

Comment: This only helps if the DLL did the same.